# Converting a gif to webp in pillow saves the first frame only

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert a gif to webp, but it's not animated anymore it just shows the first frame, how to fix that?
here's my code:

```
def make_(image):
    im = Image.open(image)
    im_io = BytesIO()
    im.save(im_io, format='WEBP')
    
    name = image.name
    name = name.replace('.gif', '.webp')

    webp = InMemoryUploadedFile(im_io, 'ImageField', name, 'image/webp',sys.getsizeof(image), None)
    return webp
```

and also I don't think replacing `.gif` with `.webp` in `name = name.replace('.gif', '.webp')` is the best approach, so if youu have any suggestions to fix that without using `os`.

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution here https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4313
I don't know why but this worked:

```
im.save(im_io, format='WEBP', save_all=True)
```